# How to checkout git repo together with externals using svn

Tags: git, svn

I have used `svn` to checkout from `https://github.com/GluuFederation/gluu-gateway/tags/v4.0.0`
i.e `svn co URL` the problem is, there is a dir named `/third-party` which has external repo URLS' that are not being checked out. I am getting a blank directory.

How can I `checkout` and make sure those externals in the `/third-party` have been checked out also?

Thank you.

Comment: how about trying to use git instead?

Answer (score 0):

The externals are called [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) and are being managed in [.gitmodules](https://github.com/GluuFederation/gluu-gateway/blob/v4.0.0/.gitmodules) file. I don't know if there is an option to checkout the submodules with `svn` but you can do it with the following `git` command

```
git clone  --recurse-submodules --branch v4.0.0 --depth=1 https://github.com/GluuFederation/gluu-gateway
```

Comment: Let me try and use that instead.

Comment: This one is having ssh connection issue especially the sub-modules

Comment: ```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Comment: Check your local git configuration. I have successfully cloned and checked out the tag v4.0.0 with all submodules using this command

Comment: That is inside `Dockerfile` ? Maybe I forgot to mention this.